# html relative path not working even though vs code displays the image using the relative path

Tags: html, image, relative-path

i am practicing html using my computer and i run the html file using the "Live Server" add-on in vscode. the image doesnt show up with the relative path:

```
<img src="../html/images/coffee background.jpeg" alt="tx"/>
```

my root folder is the `css` folder, which i have opened in vs code. `index.html` is stored in this `css` folder.

the image is stored in the `images` folder inside the `html` folder, which is stored in the folder above the `css`.

using inspect element on the img link in the browser this shows up: Cannot GET /html/images/coffee%20background.jpeg

i'm pretty sure this relative path is correct because when i click "follow link" in vs code when i hover over the link, the image shows up in vs code. why isn't the image displaying when i run the html file?

Comment: Is the file published? Also can you try with a file name like `/simple.jpg` ?

Answer (score 0):

In a Web server, you cannot get lower than the Web root, while in VSCode, you can (you can drill down to the disk root, I imagine).

So when you say,

> my root folder is the css folder, which i have opened in vs code.
> index.html is stored in this css folder.

this means that **you cannot enter a "sibling" folder of css**. Just as, when running and your root is `/var/www/customer1_pages`, you obviously cannot access "../customer2_pages/passwords.txt".

`../html/images` (but also `../../../html/images` etc.) is the same thing as `/html/images`, and (for the web server) means `<ROOT>/html/images`, which in your filesystem would be `css/html/images`.

You need to set the root folder to `html`, and place the index there. Or move images inside css.